# Help with formatting: columns

Tags: support, formatting

I am new to this site and having a few issues with formatting my question.

I am attempting to ask a question in which I need to show 3 lines of data in 3 columns (as below) but am struggling to get them to line up. [I can get them to line up in the box where you type but this doesn't translate to what would be published to the site...]

Known Values:       $X_k$ =    5 :    $Y_k$  = 5 :     $Z_k$ =   5
Predicted Values:   $X_p$ =  -95 :    $Y_p$  = 5 :     $Z_p$ = 105
Difference      $\Delta$X = -100 : $\Delta$Y = 0 : $\Delta$Z = 100

If I use blockquotes etc. I can get the columns to line up but am unable to use the subscripts and greek letters.

Is there anyway round this such than both can happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit more work, but you could do something like

```
$$
\begin{array}{lccc}
\text{Known Values:} & X_k = 5 & Y_k = 5 & Z_k = 5 \\
\text{Predicted Values:} & X_p = -95 & Y_p = 5 & Z_p = 105 \\
\text{Difference:} & \Delta X = -100 & \Delta Y = 0 & \Delta Z = 100 \\
\end{array}
$$
```

> $$
> \begin{array}{llll}
> \text{Known Values:} & X_k = 5 & Y_k = 5 & Z_k = 5 \\
> \text{Predicted Values:} & X_p = -95 & Y_p = 5 & Z_p = 105 \\
> \text{Difference:} & \Delta X = -100 & \Delta Y = 0 & \Delta Z = 100 \\
> \end{array}
> $$

Or, if you want the columns to line up at the equals signs instead,

```
$$
\begin{array}{llrclrclrcl}
\text{Known Values:} && X_k &=& 5 & Y_k &=& 5 & Z_k &=& 5 \\
\text{Predicted Values:} && X_p &=& -95 & Y_p &=& 5 & Z_p &=& 105 \\
\text{Difference:} && \Delta X &=& -100 & \Delta Y &=& 0 & \Delta Z &=& 100 \\
\end{array}
$$
```

> $$
> \begin{array}{llrclrclrcl}
> \text{Known Values:} && X_k &=& 5 & Y_k &=& 5 & Z_k &=& 5 \\
> \text{Predicted Values:} && X_p &=& -95 & Y_p &=& 5 & Z_p &=& 105 \\
> \text{Difference:} && \Delta X &=& -100 & \Delta Y &=& 0 & \Delta Z &=& 100 \\
> \end{array}
> $$

Note that, of course, this also opens up the option of using more table-like formatting...

```
$$
\begin{array}{lccc}
&X&Y&Z\\\hline
\text{Known Values:} & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
\text{Predicted Values:} & -95 & 5 & 105 \\
\text{Difference:} &  -100 & 0 & 100 \\
\end{array}
$$
```

> $$
> \begin{array}{lccc}
> &X&Y&Z\\\hline
> \text{Known Values:} & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
> \text{Predicted Values:} & -95 & 5 & 105 \\
> \text{Difference:} &  -100 & 0 & 100 \\
> \end{array}
> $$